# How to ingest JSON independent of top level node names

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure, json.net

I have an Azure Server-less Function that serves to take in a JSON payload and work on the records contained.  The function works perfectly well to do what is intended except it shouldn't matter the wrapper node name.  For example:

```
{
   "Wrapper": [{
        "Field1": "Apple",
        "Field2": "Peach",
        "Field3": "########5",
        "Field4": "Kiwi",
    }]
}
```

Should be processed the same way as:

```
{
    "OtherWrapperName": [{
        "Column1": "Apple",
        "Something": "Peach",
        "SomethingElse": "Banana",
        "Field4": "Kiwi"
    }]
}
```

Right now it seems to expect the top level node to be called "Wrapper".  Here is my attempt at this (some code has been redacted as it was unnecessary for this example):

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string InputData = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var inputData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsPayload>(InputData);

    var propertiesLookup = new Dictionary<string, ItemUpdate>();
    var propertiesRequest = new PropertySearchRequest { Registry = new List<RequestPropertySearch>() };


    int recordCounter = 0;
    foreach (var item in inputData.Wrapper)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in item.Where(property => property.Value.StartsWith("@!!!@")))
        {
            propertiesLookup[recordCounter.ToString() + "|" + kvp.Value] = new ItemUpdate
            {
                Properties = item,
                UpdateKey = kvp.Key
            };
            propertiesRequest.Registry.Add(new RequestPropertySearch
            {
                Token = kvp.Value
            });
            recordCounter++;
        }

    }

    var intermediateRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(propertiesRequest, Formatting.Indented);
    HttpResponseMessage response = MakeRequest(serviceUrl, intermediateRequest, securityHeaderName, securityHeaderValue);

    var responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var intermediateData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertySearchResponse>(responseBodyAsText.Result);
    recordCounter = 0;
    foreach (var item in intermediateData.Registry)
    {
        if (item.Value != null)
        {
            var itemToUpdate = propertiesLookup[recordCounter.ToString() + "|" + item.Token];
            itemToUpdate.Properties[itemToUpdate.UpdateKey] = item.Value;
            if (directive.ToLower() == "s")
            {
                itemToUpdate.Properties[$"@{itemToUpdate.UpdateKey}"] = item.Token;
            }
            // recordCounter++;
        }
        recordCounter++;
    }

    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputData, Formatting.Indented);


    //return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

Models:

```
public class ItemsPayload
{
    //public string Directive { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Wrapper { get; set; }
}

public class PropertySearchRequest
{
    public List<RequestPropertySearch> Registry { get; set; }
}

public class RequestPropertySearch
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
}

public class PropertySearchResponse
{
    public List<ResponsePropertySearch> Registry { get; set; }
}

public class ResponsePropertySearch
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string ProcessId { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Remote { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class ItemUpdate
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }

    public string UpdateKey { get; set; }
}
```

I think the ItemsPayload class property "Wrapper" is causing this as if you change that to something else and rename the node in the JSON it works fine, but I want it to be independent of the name of the top level node.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple `JsonConverter` for your `ItemsPayload` to handle the varying wrapper name.

```
public class ItemsPayloadConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ItemsPayload);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        ItemsPayload payload = new ItemsPayload();
        // Get the first property of the outer JSON object regardless of its name
        // and populate the payload from it
        JProperty wrapper = obj.Properties().FirstOrDefault();
        if (wrapper != null)
        {
            payload.Wrapper = wrapper.Value.ToObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(serializer);
        }
        return payload;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, just annotate your `ItemsPayload` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this and it should work with no other changes to your code:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ItemsPayloadConverter))]
public class ItemsPayload
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Wrapper { get; set; }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9q4tgW